# How to make chart background transparent

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using the lightning chart and would like to make the background transparent I tried setting the following on my chart but it just gives me a black background

```
  .setChartBackgroundFillStyle( new SolidFill({
    // A (alpha) is optional - 255 by default
    color: ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0,0)
   })
  )
  .setBackgroundFillStyle( new SolidFill({
    // A (alpha) is optional - 255 by default
    color: ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0,0)
   })
  )
  .setFittingRectangleFillStyle(
    new SolidFill({
      // A (alpha) is optional - 255 by default
      color: ColorRGBA(255, 0, 0,0)
     })
   )
   .setChartBackgroundStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
   .setBackgroundStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
   .setFittingRectangleStrokeStyle(emptyLine)
```

Do let me know what I'm missing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In LightningChart JS version 2.0.0 and above it's possible to set the chart background color to transparent with [`chart.setChartBackgroundFillStyle(transparentFill)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.0.0/classes/chartxy.html#setchartbackgroundfillstyle) and [`chart.setBackgroundFillStyle(transparentFill)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.0.0/classes/chartxy.html#setbackgroundfillstyle)

```js
const {
  lightningChart,
  transparentFill,
  emptyFill
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()
  .setChartBackgroundFillStyle(transparentFill)
  .setBackgroundFillStyle(emptyFill)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@2.0.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

---

Old answer:

<strike>LightningChart JS currently doesn't support transparent background. Version 2.0 will support transparent backgrounds.</strike>

When version 2.0 is released you can use `.setBackgroundFillStyle(emptyFill)` and `.setChartBackgroundFillStyle(emptyFill)` to make a chart with transparent background. Alternatively you can use a `SolidFill` with partially transparent color.

Comment: Thanks really looking forward to the release of version two

Answer (score 0):

You can use css "**background-color:transparent**"

Comment: This is a chart that uses the html canvas I tried setting the canvas background to  transparent but there seems to be something in the libraries settings I might be missing